# GraphQL Extend method method from generic java class

Tags: java, spring, generics, graphql, boot

I re-write from Spring boot Rest API to GraphQL

I have Rest Controller generic, common for all controller

```java
public class GenericController<E, P extends Serializable>{

    @Autowired
    private GenericService<E, P> genericService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> findById(@PathVariable P id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(genericService.findById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/findAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> findAll() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(genericService.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> create(@RequestBody @Valid E e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(genericService.save(e), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

And controllers extend generic controller with generic type is Entity

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Customer")
public class CustomerController extends GenericController<CustomerEntity, Long> implements GraphQLQueryResolver{
    public List<CustomerEntity> findAllCustomer(){//This method is only for GraphQL
        return findAll();
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Product")
public class ProductController extends GenericController<ProductEntity, Long> implements GraphQLQueryResolver{
    public List<ProductEntity> findAllProduct(){//This method is only for GraphQL
        return findAll();
    }
}
```

GraphQL schema

```json
type CustomerEntity {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
}

type ProductEndity {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    price: Int!
}

type Query {
    findAllCustomer: [CustomerEntity]
    findAllProduct: [ProductEndity]
}
```

with this design, no need write code CRUD method in CustomerController/ProductController, but still using CRUD method (findById, findAll, create,...) from generic for CustomerEntity and ProductEntity

With RestAPI, I using 1 method name (findAll) for 2 path /Customer & /Product

```
http://localhost:7888/Customer/findAll
http://localhost:7888/Product/findAll
```

But, with GraphQL, I must using 2 method findAllCustomer & findAllProduct

```json
query {
    findAllCustomer{
        id name email
    }
}
```

```json
query {
    findAllProduct{
        id name price
    }
}
```

**Question:**
How can I just use 1 method name (findAll) for both Customer and Product, No need to write separate methods for each controller, similar RestAPI

Just like that (I think so :) )

```
query {
  Customer{
    findAll{
        id name email
    }
  }
}
```

```
query {
  Product{
    findAll{
        id name price
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

In GraphQL you can perform multiple queries in a single request. For example:

```
query giveMeAllTheThings {
  allCustomers {
    id 
    name
    email
  }
  allProducts {
    id
    name
    price
  }
}
```

This assumes the following query definitions:

```
type Query {
  allCustomers: [Customer]
  allProducts: [Product]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. I used queries findAllCustomer and findAllProduct, it work fine. However, I'm looking for another way to reuse methods findAll/findById/create in generics class but without writing any more method for each Customer / Product entity

Comment: Then you'll need to pass in the table name as a parameter to your generic functions.